# How to use std::sort() for a long long vector in c++?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have an vector of type long long and wish to sort it in ascending order but I think I am misunderstanding the usage of std::sort().

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

...

std::vector<long long> numbers (4);
numbers[0] = 6;
numbers[1] = 4;
numbers[2] = 3;
numbers[3] = 7;
```

I have tried to use:

```
std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::greater<long long>());
```

but I get an error which says

```
std::vector<long long int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
```

Also, ideally I would like to sort the vector only between two elements, e.g. between numbers[1] and numbers[2]; but using these values for the first two parameters does not seem to work.

Thanks.

Edit: Also, I'm using g++ compiler

Comment: `std::greater<>()` actually causes them to be sorted in descending order.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code as written, provided your readers add the appropriate `#include` directives and a bit more structure. So the problem is in the code that you didn't show.

Comment: @iwin: Well, I doubt that any of the lines you posted can possibly generate the error message you quoted. Can you reproduce the issue in a compact and contiguous piece of code, like a `void foo()` function?

Answer (score 11):

Sort already sorts in ascending order, so all you need is

```
std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
```

The code you posted would sort in **descending** order, and would work as is, but you must `#include <functional>`:

```
#include <functional> // for std::greater, std::less
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

....
std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::greater<long long>());
```

Comment: Or sort in reverse order using `rbegin` and `rend`.

Comment: @PeterWood good point, I hadn't even thought of that. I wanted to emphasize the error in OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

What you have now is is already correct. (Assuming it properly expresses your intent. Do you need *ascending* or *descending* sort order?).

The error message you are getting is probably caused by your forgetting to include some header file. It just happened that implementation of some important part of the algorithm (`std::greater`?) got included only partially, for `std::string`, but not for the general case.

Make sure you included `<vector>`, `<algorithm>` and `<functional>`, the latter being the most likely candidate for the missing header. Did you include `<functional>`?

Comment: Except that it would sort in descending order. But yes, the problem is probably a missing `#include <functional>`

Comment: Unfortunately I had already included <vector>, <algorithm>, and <functional> but get this error anyway.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `std::sort` will put them into ascending order.

If you want them descending, iterate backwards over the container:

```
std::sort(numbers.rbegin(), numbers.rend());
```